# android progressbar

Tags: android

hi could some one show me how to add a progress bar to this method :

```
public boolean sendFile(String path,String ip, int port)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {


            String[] str = ip.split("\\.");

            byte[] IP = new byte[str.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

                IP[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str[i]);


            }
            Socket socket = getSocket(InetAddress.getByAddress(IP), port);
            if (socket == null) {
                Log.i("SO sendFILE","");

                return false;
            }

            Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-1");
            File  f = new File(path);
            String filename=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            System.out.println("filename:"+filename); 
            fin.filename = "~"+filename;
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( socket.getOutputStream() );

            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(f);
            Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-2");
            byte [] buffer  = new byte [(int)f.length()];
            System.out.println("SO sendFile f.length();" + f.length());
            int bytesRead =0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                System.out.println("SO sendFile" + bytesRead +filename);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            fileIn.close();
            Log.i("SocketOP", "sendFILE-3");






        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;           
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //  Toast.makeText(this, "Lvbvhhging...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;     
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, can you help me ,please?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540814/how-to-show-a-progress-bar-during-the-creation-of-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProgressDialog pbarDialog =  new ProgressDialog( mContext ); 
pbarDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
pbarDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pbarDialog.setCancelable(false);
pbarDialog.setMax(100);
 pbarDialog .setProgress(0);
 pbarDialog.show();
    while ((bytesRead = fileIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
      //get the previous value of progress bar 
                    int old_value = pbarDialog .getProgress();
                    //calculate how much did you read from the file
                    int new_read =(int)( ((float)  bytesRead/f.length()) )*100 ) ;
                    //add the new read to the old_value
                    int value = new_read+old_value;
                    pbarDialog.setProgress(value);              
      System.out.println("SO sendFile" + bytesRead +filename);
                }
 pbarDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: where do i construct the bar? this same class or the class im calling this from?

Comment: you can have an activity that contains the progress bar  and call this function that load the file in another thread

Comment: i have class called "messaging" that calls this method. this method is in another class called "imservice" now please tell me where should the bar be placed and from where it should be called. thank you so much.

Comment: which class is the activity class ??

Comment: messaging. imservice is a service.

Comment: call this inside your service and pass "this" keyword to the progressDialog constructor

Comment: it says the progressDialog isnt defined for my class :(

Comment: i cant run it. its got errors cuz of it. if i put null in the constructor then the error goes away

Comment: you don't have an activity in your program ?

Comment: look here is the scenario. messagin activity has a button "sendFile" on clicking it takes me to "fileBrowser" there i get the path,put it in extras come bk to "messagin" then call imservice.sendFile. it calls SocketOperator.sendFile..in socketoperator i have the sendFile code i pasted in the question. this is the whole scenario..

Comment: okey you must provide Activity context to the constructor pass "this" keyword to the sendFile like this imservice.sendFile(this) and the sendFile is like this sendFile(Context context) and in the progressDialog constuctor pass context paramerter

Comment: imService.sendFile takes its own parameters..how can i pass THIS to it?

Comment: public boolean sendFile(Context context,String path,String ip, int port) then in ur activity call imservice.send(this,...,...

Comment: like i said..this boolean sendFile method resides in the SOCKETOPERATOR class. not in the imSerive.let me explain again. MESSAGING calls FILEBROWSER and comes back to MESSAGING then it calls IMSERVICE...IMSERVICE calls SOCKETOPERATOR, and socketoperator has this boolean method..thank you and m sorry m being stupid..

Comment: okey i didn't understand what are u saying but i will give you a hint how you can do it the constructor of PorgressDialog accept an activity context , look for a way to pass it to your sendFile method for example as i said above if i have an activity called A and i want to call your sendFile method then inside the A class i will call it like that object.sendFile(this,.....) so this refer to the Activity and you should add this parameter to the sendFile method

Comment: i have changed the methods like u have said. now what do i do next to run the progress bar?

Comment: anyone out there?? and also could u tell me do i have to add the progress bar to the xml layout?

Comment: @hardy.exe: If the answer to this question did not satisfy all your needs, please consider posting a new question that reflects the progress you've made.  You will get much better responses than you do from asking questions in comment form.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to run that function from the UI thread in order to show a progress bar, but then you wouldn't get to see any progress until the function finished. The right approach for what you are trying to do is an AsyncTask, check

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: thank you. i have checked it alread but i dont know how to implement it. could u help me with it? i mean the method i put up, could u tell me how to show a bar for that? thank you

Comment: Is this action something that's going to take a long time and should probably run in the background? If so, consider using a service, namely IntentService.