# how create progress bar UI that appear during PDF creation

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-studio

how can i create `progress bar` UI that appear during PDF creation and that stop when PDF creation is finished?

TwoFragment.java

```
public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{

                private View v;
                Intent chooser=null;
                String myInt="";

                public TwoFragment() {
                    // Required empty public constructor
                }

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
                    Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newbutton);
                    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            //sendemail();
                            createPDF();
                            viewPDF();



                        }
                    });
                    TextView titolo3 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.result);
                    TextView titolo2 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.result2);
                    TextView titolo4 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.resultpizze);

                    //TextView titolo = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.quantità3);

                  /*  Bundle bundle2=getArguments();
                    if(bundle2 != null){
                        String string = bundle2.getString("scelta2", null);
                        titolo3.setText(string);
                    }*/

                    Bundle bundle2=getArguments();
                    if(bundle2 != null){
                        myInt = bundle2.getString("scelta2", null);
                       titolo3.setText(myInt);
                    }

                    Bundle bundle3=getArguments();
                    if(bundle3 != null){
                       // String myInt3 = bundle3.getString("totalebirre", null);
                       //  cazzo2=Integer.parseInt(myInt3);
                       int cazzo2=bundle3.getInt("totalebirre");
                        titolo2.setText(String.valueOf(cazzo2));



                    }
                    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
                    if(bundle != null){
                        // String myInt2 = bundle2.getString("totalepizze", null);
                        //   cazzo=Integer.parseInt(myInt2);
                        //titolo2.setText(myInt2);
                        String string=bundle.getString("scelta3", null);
                         titolo4.setText(string);

                    }



                    return rootView;
                }
               /* public void sendemail(){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                    String[] to={"marco_marcoletto@hotmail.it"};
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,to);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ciao");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "zao");
                    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    chooser=intent.createChooser(intent,"manda email");
                    startActivity(chooser);
                }*/
               public void createPDF() {

                   Document doc = new Document();

                   try {
                       String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                               .getAbsolutePath() + "/droidText";

                       File dir = new File(path);
                       if (!dir.exists())
                           dir.mkdirs();

                       Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

                       File file = new File(dir, "sample.pdf");
                       FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                       PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

                       // open the document
                       doc.open();
                       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                               .getResources(), R.drawable.androtuto);
                       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                       Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                       myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

                       // add image to document
                       doc.add(myImg);

                       Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph(myInt);
                   Log.d("ciao",myInt);

                       Font paraFont = new Font(Font.COURIER);
                       p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                       p1.setFont(paraFont);

                       // add paragraph to document
                       doc.add(p1);

                       Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Ciao");
                       Font paraFont2 = new Font(Font.COURIER, 14.0f, Color.GREEN);
                       p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
                       p2.setFont(paraFont2);

                       doc.add(p2);

                       stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext()
                               .getResources(), R.drawable.android);
                       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                       myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                       myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

                       // add image to document
                       doc.add(myImg);

                       // set footer
                       Phrase footerText = new Phrase("Pied de page ");
                       HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
                       doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);

                   } catch (DocumentException de) {
                       Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
                   } finally {
                       doc.close();
                   }

               }
                public void viewPDF(){
                    String path = "/sdcard/droidText/sample.pdf";
                    File targetFile = new File(path);
                    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);

                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");

                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
```

ThreeFragment.java
FRAGMENT FROM WHERE I PASS VARIABLES:

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment implements
        android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ListView lv2;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    ListView lv;

    ArrayList<Birra> birraList;
    BirraAdapter biAdapter;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;
    Planet p;
    String myInt="";



    PlanetAdapter.PlanetHolder holder;


    public ThreeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyListFragment mlf=new MyListFragment();

                mlf.showResult(v);
              // MyListFragment.showResult(v);
                showResult2(v);


            }
        });
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        lv2 = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview2);
        displayBirraList();
    }


    private void displayBirraList() {

        birraList = new ArrayList<Birra>();
        birraList.add(new Birra("Paulaner", 6, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Forst", 7, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Peroni", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Corona", 5, "€"));
        birraList.add(new Birra("Nastro Azzurro", 4, "€"));
        biAdapter = new BirraAdapter(birraList, getContext()) {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int pos = lv2.getPositionForView(buttonView);
                if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    Birra b = birraList.get(pos);
                    b.setSelected(isChecked);


            /*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Pizza: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                }


            }


        };


        lv2.setAdapter(biAdapter);
    }


    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


        /*int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);
        if (pos != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            Planet p = planetList.get(pos);
            p.setSelected(isChecked);


            *//**//**//**//*Toast.makeText(
                getActivity(),
                "Clicked on Planet: " + p.getName() + ". State: is "
                        + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*//**//**//**//*
        }
*/
    }


    public void showResult2(View v) {
        String result = "Selected Product are :";
        int totalAmount = 0;
       // String a = "";


        for (Birra b : biAdapter.getBox()) {

            if (b.selected) {

                result += "\n" + b.name + " " + b.distance + "€" + "q.tà :" + b.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(b.getQuantità());
                totalAmount += b.distance * quantitaInt;
              //  a=String.valueOf(totalAmount);


            }
        }
      /*  for (Planet p : plAdapter.getBox()) {
            if (p.isSelected()) {


                result += "\n" + p.getName() + " " + p.getDistance() + "€" + "q.tà :" + p.getQuantità();
                int quantitaInt = Integer.parseInt(p.getQuantità());
                //totalAmount2+=p.distance * quantitaInt;
                //z=String.valueOf(totalAmount2);


            }
        }*/



        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result + "\n" +myInt + "\n" + "Total Amount:=" + totalAmount + "€", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Bundle bun2 = new Bundle();
            bun2.putString("scelta2", result);
            TwoFragment fgsearch2 = new TwoFragment();
            fgsearch2.setArguments(bun2);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction2.replace(R.id.content_main, fgsearch2);
            transaction2.commit();

            Bundle bun = new Bundle();
           // bun.putString("totalebirre", a);
        bun.putInt("totalebirre", totalAmount);
            TwoFragment fgsearch = new TwoFragment();
            fgsearch.setArguments(bun);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_main2, fgsearch);
            transaction.commit();




    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android progressbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374882/android-progressbar)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** - Declare a global variable - private ProgressBar pdfProgress;

**Step 2** - Create a progress bar widget in your respective layour.xml(fragment_two) and give it an id.

**Step 3** - In onCreate() method of TwoFragment, write this code just after defining the rootView.
    pdfProgress = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id."your progress bar id");

**Step 4** - just above createPDF(); write this - 
    pdfProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

**Step 5** - just below createPDF(); write this -
    pdfProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

**

### Updated Answer

**

Try this code in your TwoFragment - onClick()-

```
Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.newbutton);
ProgressBar pdfProgress = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //sendemail();
                        pdfProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        createPDF();
                        pdfProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        viewPDF();



                    }
                });
```

The fragment_two.xml (your fragment layout xml) must contain a progress bar that looks like this - (you can add drawables too, might wanna look at a tutorial for that)

```
    <ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"/>
```

Comment: Actually, you do not need to declare the progress bar globally, you can declare it within the onCreate itself since you are not using the progress bar elsewhere in TwoFragment. 
Declaring progress bar globally will be handy if you need to use it for other purposes within TwoFragment.

Comment: before that i click on button i see progress bar...while progress bar must appear when i click button...

Comment: sorry, can you write me also XML about progress bar,please?

Comment: Check out the updated answer. Please vote and then mark it as answer if it helped thanks.

Comment: the progress bar appear before that i click on button...why?

Comment: If you are having the pdfProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); inside the onClick event then the progress bar will show up when you click.

If you are having ptoblems try setting the pdfProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE), before invoking the onClick method.

Comment: Provide me your entire code, I would like to see which widget your onClick() method is referencing to.

Comment: Async Task is too complex topic to use for something as simple as progress bar. Not a good practice to activate a progress bar on a background thread. It must be done on the UI thread. 

Anyways, happy that your code is working, cheers.

Comment: In method background where i call method createpdf() how must write to make show numbers about creation PDF?

Comment: If you want to show the progress percentage, it would make sense to use Async Task, although you can do it without it as well.

Comment: In my app appear only bar circle...i want show also percentage...can you help me?

Comment: Here is an example - 
http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html

Hope it helps

Comment: If you can help me....here there is my cose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540814/how-to-show-a-progress-bar-during-the-creation-of-a-file